# glut won't work on my computer

Tags: opengl, glut

[image]

when I try to create a cube in using c++ and glut but it returns the errors;

```
q-3d.cpp: (.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `glutInit', 
q-3d.cpp: (.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow', 
q-3d.cpp: (.text+0xde): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize',
q-3d.cpp: (.text+0xed): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition', 
q-3d.cpp: (.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc' and 
q-3d.cpp: (.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
```

Comment: The error you're seeing is a linker error (source code is correct, but compiler fails to find the glut library when assembling the final binary). You need to link your program with glut when compiling: try to add this library in your makefile or in the project options of your IDE.

Comment: thank you so much you are a true hero.